# When to use getOrElse and orElse?

Tags: scala

```
// getOrElse if it failed output value of else
trait Option[+A] {
def orElse[B >: A](f: => Option[B]): Option[B]
def getOrElse[B >: A](f: => B): B
}
```

From the code above, I can't think of concrete example that I would prefer one over another.
Can anyone give me example of when to use what?
Or main differences of the two

Comment: Main difference is return type. If you need to continue to work with `Option` then you use `orElse` if you need to work with the underlying type - use `getOrElse`

Comment: `getOrElse` is what you use to remove the `Option` layer, you either get the value inside or the default. `orElse` on the other hand doesn't remove the `Option` context, rather it allows you to combine two options into one, where the second one works as a fallback in case the first one wasn't defined; but doesn't guarantee the second one will be defined.

Comment: Option -> Option orElse otherwise getOrElse

Comment: If both your original plan and your fallback plan can fail, then you can use `orElse` to combine these two potentially failing plans into one potentially failing plan. If your original plan can fail, but your backup plan is guaranteed to succeed, then you can use `getOrElse`, and unconditionally obtain a guaranteed solution.

Answer (score 4):

The use cases are slightly different between `getOrElse` and `orElse`.

You use `getOrElse(y)` when you want to get the value out of an `Option` monad. In the case of `Some(x)` you'll get back the `x` otherwise, you'll get back the `y` that you specified as a fallback. I use this as the very final step when I want to get the final result of executing a pipeline of operations on optionals.

Example:

```
val greeting: String = 
  getUserById(1)
    .map(_.name)
    .map("hello, " + _)
    .getOrElse("hello, unknown user")
```

However, for `orElse`, I usually use this when I'm executing a pipeline of operations and there's a step that I always want to execute even if one the previous steps returns a `None`. So in a way, you can think of `orElse` as a way to turn a `None` into a `Some` so that it can be used in a subsequent computation.

Example

```
getUserById(1)
  .map(getMovieRecommendationsForUser(_)) 
  .orElse(getDefaultMovieRecommendations()) // if any of the previous steps return a None, I still want to return some default movie list
  .map(_.sorted)
  .map(_.take(10))
  ... // do more stuff
```

Hope this makes sense.